# Case when intent is null with 'START_REDELIVER_INTENT' is possible?

Tags: android, android-service

In an extended class from Service class when we use the onStartCommand method with the return value 'START_REDELIVER_INTENT', the method will be called with the last intent that was delivered to the service.

Is there a case when the service returns to the method returns Intent equal to null, taking into account that the last delivered intent is not null?